# Logging into Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am new to Oracle (coming from a SQL Server world). This is going to probably be some simple newbie question. I just did a fresh install of Oracle 12c Express. The install was successful, but now I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to log in.

According to [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NXDQI/toc.htm#NXDQI122), I should be able to log in using `SYSMAN` as the username and the password I entered during installation. I have tried to log into the web interface. It says `Login denied; invalid username/password`. I also tried to log in using Oracle SQL Developer and had the same issue. Finally, I tried logging in using SQL*Plus from the command line. Same issue.

Can someone please tell me how to initially log in after a fresh install of Oracle 12c?

Comment: first question would be, did you create a database or just install the oracle software?

Comment: try 'SYSTEM' user

Comment: @davegreen100 - Yes, I installed both.

Answer (score -1):

Now you can go and read this, if you haven't already... ;-)

[Oracle 12c concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cncptdba.htm#CNCPT827)